# Call a block from an asynchronous callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, asynccallback

I try to call a completion block from an asynchronous callback.
but sometimes I have the following crash:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100bc58e8 swift_unknownRelease + 8
1  Appname                         0x100270370 thunk (AccountAlreadyExistsViewController.swift)
2  Appname                         0x10021a060 __52-[UserService request:withCompletion:]_block_invoke (UserService.m:1565)
3  Appname                         0x10005d2e0 __59-[NetworkService requestPost:withParameter:success:failed:]_block_invoke (NetworkService.m:63)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1818554bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x18185547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18185ab84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
7  CoreFoundation                 0x181dc0dd8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
8  CoreFoundation                 0x181dbec40 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181ce8d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
10 GraphicsServices               0x1835d0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
11 UIKit                          0x186fbdf70 UIApplicationMain + 204
12 Appname                         0x1002bc334 main (AppDelegate.swift:18)
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1818868b8 (Missing)
```

The code is the following:

```
- (void)request:(UserEntity *)userEntity withCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *dict, NSError *error))completion
{

  NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?dest=%@&type=%@",k_SERVER_REQUES, userEntity.id, "abc"];

  __block NSNumber *userContactId = userEntity.id;


  [self requestPost:url withParameter:nil success:^(NSInteger status, NSString *message, id data) {
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableDictionary *rs = data;

    if (status == 1)
    { //If no error
      FriendModel *friendModel = [FriendModel friendModelWithFriend:"id1" owner:"id2"];
      PLog(@"Removing user from database");
      [friendModel remove];
    }else{
      error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"request" code:-1 userInfo:@{@"status":[NSNumber numberWithInt:status]}];
    }
    //CRASH HERE SOMETIMES
    if (completion) completion(rs, error); 

  } failed:^(NSString* s) {
    // CRASH HERE SOMETIMES
    if(completion) completion(nil, [NSError errorWithDomain:@"request" code:-1 userInfo:@{@"detail":s}]); 
  }];

}
```

Do I need to create a weak reference of the completion block before the asynchronous block and then create a strong reference of it within the block? It looks like overkill. My theory is that the completion block gets released just after calling the asynchronous call, and the crash happens... 
The completion block is not nil but the memory will actually be freed.

Apple recommend things like that... 
What do you think? And how should I write it?

//Avoid retain cycle
//https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html

**EDIT**

Calling request from Swift

```
myService.request(user, withCompletion: { (dict, error) -> Void in
      if let err = error {
        log.error("Add, delete or modified request: \(err)")
      }
      //This completion() block is from the current function
      completion?(response: nil, err: error)
})
```

Comment: I think you want to make a copy of `completion` within the inner block.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. Or maybe I have to copy it to a __block variable but I don't want to do random things. I hope somebody will be able to explain clearly what to do here.

Comment: Well my thinking is that the method returns, the completion block is freed and then the inner block accesses it.  Making an additional reference to it early in the inner block to will retain a copy of the completion block.

Comment: I understand but I don't think that works for blocks.

Comment: How are you calling `request`?

Comment: I updated my post with the Call